# yii2 losing user identity after login redirect

Tags: redirect, identity, yii2

i have looked at the other similar questions, and while this one  ([Yii2 user identity loss after page redirection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27738175/yii2-user-identity-loss-after-page-redirection)) asks pretty much the same question, there is no solution that applies to my situation.

i have created a new identity class, i have implemented all the necessary methods and implemented the IdentityInterface. note that it does NOT extend ActiveRecord, but rather extends my own base Model class that does not derive from AR.

everything seems to work fine, i can log in and be correctly authenticated. i have traced the code and i can see that my identity class is correctly set in Yii::$app->user after IdentityInterface::validatePassword() and User::login() have been called.

however, once the login succeeds and the user is redirected, Yii::$app->user contains an empty IdentityInterface, rather than the one that was there immediately prior to the redirect.

in SiteController::actionLogin(), i have modified the code from:

```
return $this->goHome();
```

to:

```
$tmp = $this->goHome();
// echo '<pre>';var_dump(Yii::$app->user);echo '</pre>';exit;
return($tmp);
```

and i can see that Yii::$app->user still has the correct identity up until the return() statement.

can anyone tell me why i am losing my identity? i have traced through everything i can think of: yii\web\Controller, yii\base\Controller, yii\web\Response,  SiteController, yii\web\User, etc...

any help at all would be greatly appreciated. thanks!

Comment: forgot to mention that i do not see anything about the identity stored in the Yii::$app->session. so not sure how the identity is typically maintained between requests. i traced through all the same code while using a standard activerecord-based identity, which does work correctly even after the login redirect. but again i could see nothing different: the identity was there up until the SiteController::actionLogin() returns, and in this case it is there afterwards as well.

Comment: is it possible that activerecord does something explicityly to retain the identity between requests (which i would have to replicate in my code)?

Comment: Are you using the Yii default identity class or did you implement your own? If you implemented your own post the code for it. Otherwise post the code for your model.

Comment: Perhaps something is wrong with your session store. It might not saving your session.

Comment: thanks for the responses!  nterms: if it is the session store, it would only be a session problem when i am NOT using the activerecord class, as all is fine when i do use the AR class. mihaip: i did create my own identity class, and i will post the code shortly. i was not aware that yii provides a default implementation class of IdentityInterface that does not use activerecord. if so, i will happily subclass that.

Comment: i see in the yii2 documentation that there is a class "app\models\User" which implements IdentityInterface without extending ActiveRecord (as opposed to common\models\User, which does extend AR).  however, i cannot find that class file anywhere in my yii2 installation. am i missing something?

Comment: duh!  i just found it in the basic application template (i have only been using the advanced template).

Comment: so @Laz is this issue fixed? and how did you fix it?

Comment: i never did fix this. several folks have responded below, and i appreciate the responses. however, every one of them ignores the fact that i explicitly do NOT want to use active record, period. i thought i made that clear in the question, but i guess not.

Answer (score 5):

Same problem, after 3 days find solution and I it working.
My User model is:

```
namespace app\models;

use Yii;
class User extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord implements \yii\web\IdentityInterface
{
    public $username;

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'tbl_users';
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['name', 'email', 'password'], 'required'],
            [['email'], 'unique'],
            [['role', 'status'], 'integer'],
            [['created', 'last_update'], 'safe'],
            [['name', 'email', 'password'], 'string', 'max' => 250]
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'id' => 'ID',
            'name' => 'Name',
            'email' => 'Email',
            'password' => 'Password',
            'role' => 'Role',
            'status' => 'Status',
            'created' => 'Created',
            'last_update' => 'Last Update',
        ];
    }
    public function getAuthKey() {

    }

    public function getId() {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function validateAuthKey($authKey) {

    }

    public static function findIdentity($id) {

    }

    public static function findIdentityByAccessToken($token, $type = null) {

    }
    public static function findByEmail($email)
    {
        return static::findOne(array('email'=>$email));
    }

    public function validatePassword($password)
    {
        return $this->password === $password;
    }
}
```

I change:

```
public static function findIdentity($id) {

}
```

to:

```
public static function findIdentity($id) {
    return self::findOne(array('id'=>$id));
}
```

It working for me.

Comment: Changing the findIdentity function to actually return a User instance solved my problem as well

Comment: thanks! I was going in circles before I found this.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem. I had my custom class implementing yii\web\IdentityInterface. I made sure that session was enabled and enableAutologin was also true, but I had no luck at all.

Finally, I realized that in config/web.php there's a setting 'user' => [ 'identityClass' => 'app\models\User', 'enableAutoLogin' => true]

Of course, the identityClass is the default in a basic yii application. After setting this value to my custom class, identity was finally persisted.

Answer (score 2):

try like this

1. implement `implements \yii\web\IdentityInterface` for your Active
   record and Implement all method from `\yii\web\IdentityInterface`.
2. declare $users as static variable as `private static $users = [];` in your class.
3. Alter `findByUsername()` function for Get user details form Username.
   In Config file add

   'user' => ['identityClass' => 'app\models\active record class',
    'enableAutoLogin' => true,
     ],

   ```
   class User extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord                                     
   implements\yii\web\IdentityInterface {

   private $_user = false;
   public $rememberMe = true;
   /*
    * static variable
    */
   private static $users = [];

   /**
    * @inheritdoc
    */
   public static function tableName() {
       return 'user';
   }

   /**
    * @inheritdoc
    */
   public function rules() {
       return [
           [['username', 'email', 'password', 'loginType'], 'required'],

       ];
   }

   /**
    * @inheritdoc
    */
   public function attributeLabels() {
       return [
           'id' => Yii::t('app', 'ID'),
           'username' => Yii::t('app', 'Username'),

           'email' => Yii::t('app', 'Email'),
           'password' => Yii::t('app', 'Password'),

       ];
   }

   /**
    * Logs in a user using the provided username and password.
    * @return boolean whether the user is logged in successfully
    */
   public function login() {
       if ($this->validate()) {
           return Yii::$app->user->login($this->getUser(), $this->rememberMe ? 3600 * 24 * 30 : 0);
       } else {
           return false;
       }
   }

   /**
    * Finds user by [[username]]
    *
    * @return User|null
    */
   public function getUser() {
       if ($this->_user === false) {
           $this->_user = self::findByUsername($this->username);
       }

       return $this->_user;
   }

   public function validatePassword($password) {
       if ($this->password == md5($password)) {
           return true;
       }
       return false;
   }

   public static function findIdentity($id) {
       return static::findOne($id);
   }

   public static function findIdentityByAccessToken($token, $type = null) {
       return static::findOne(['access_token' => $token]);
   }

   public function getId() {
       return $this->id;
   }

   public function getAuthKey() {
       return $this->authkey;
   }

   public function validateAuthKey($authKey) {
       return $this->authkey === $authKey;
   }

   public static function findByUsername($username) {
       /*
        * Get Record from Usertable
        */
       $user = User::findOne(["username" => $username]);
       if (!empty($user)) {
           /* Create array with your active record like below */
           $identity_use = ['id' => $user['id'],
               'username' => $user['username'],
               'password' => $user['password'],
               'authKey' => '',
               'accessToken' =>'',];
           return new static($identity_use);
       }
       return null;
   }
   ```

   }

Answer (score 2):

Another simple mistake that could result in session loss would be calling

```
$this->redirect(...);
```

instead of

```
return $this->redirect(...);
```

As Yii does not call `die()` or `exit()` in this method and the code on the lines following your redirect will be executed. Being used to CodeIgniter, I had assumed this and it took me days to figure it out.

Answer (score -1):

I hope this can help you

```
<?php

namespace app\models;

use Yii;

class User extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord implements      \yii\web\IdentityInterface {

private $_notification;

public static function tableName()
{
    return 'users';
}

public function setNotification($n) {
    Yii::$app->session['user_' .$this->id . '_notification'] = $n;
}

public function getNotification() {
    $n = Yii::$app->session['user_' .$this->id . '_notification'];
    Yii::$app->session['user_' .$this->id . '_notification'] = NULL;
    return $n;
}

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['email', 'password', 'first_name'], 'required'],
        [['role'], 'integer'],
        [['email', 'first_name'], 'string', 'max' => 128],
        [['password'], 'string', 'max' => 32]
    ];
}

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function attributeLabels()
{
    return [
        'id' => 'ID',
        'email' => 'E-mail',
        'password' => 'Пароль',
        'first_name' => 'Имя',
        'role' => 'Роль',
    ];
}

public static function findByEmail($email) {
    return self::find()->where(['email' => $email])->one();
}

public function validatePassword($password) {
    if ($this->password == md5($password)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

public static function findIdentity($id)
{
    return static::findOne($id);
}

public static function findIdentityByAccessToken($token, $type = null)
{
    return static::findOne(['access_token' => $token]);
}

public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

public function getAuthKey()
{
    return $this->authkey;
}

public function validateAuthKey($authKey)
{
    return $this->authkey === $authKey;
}

}
```

Comment: i use Active Record in my model: class User extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord implements \yii\web\IdentityInterface. 

I supposed that model loses session params after redirect without saving.
In this way i push some vars in session Yii::$app->session['user_' .$this->id . '_notification'] = $n. 

in my application i should clear notification after showing. 
and i clear it getter - Yii::$app->session['user_' .$this->id . '_notification'] = NULL;