# Yii 2 Identity interface data is lost after redirect

Tags: php, session, cookies, yii, yii2

I have created my Yii 2 application. In my database there is a table user having the following fields: `firstName`, `lastName`, `username` and `password`, 'authKey'.

Using Gii tool I created a model for the user table. In order to implement login functionality, I extended this class from IdentityInterface and I implemented all methods. Here is method list:

```
public static function findIdentityByAccessToken($token, $type = null)
{
    throw new NotSupportedException();
}

  public static function findIdentity($id)
{
    Admin::findOne($id)
}

public function getId()
{
    return this->id;
}

 public function getAuthKey()
{
    return $this->authKey
}


 public function validateAuthKey($authKey)
{
    return $this->authKey = $authKey;
}

public static function findByUsername($username)
{
    return static::find(array('username'=>$username));
}

public function validatePassword($password) {
    return $this->password == $password;//Just for demonstration purposes
}
```

I changed my config file (user component to be equal to this):

```
'user' => [
    'identityClass' => 'app\models\Admin',
    'enableAutoLogin' => true,
],
```

In `LoginController`, after line

```
if($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->login()) {
```

I print

```
var_dump(Yii::$app->user->identity);exit;
```

user identity property, and the vlaues are set normally. As soon as I redirect user to any other page

```
 var_dump(Yii::$app->user->identity); exit;
```

is equal to `null`.

Can someone explain me what is happening?

NOTE: The following posts are not helpful:

[yii2 losing user identity after login redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28155851/yii2-losing-user-identity-after-login-redirect)

[Yii2 user identity loss after page redirection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27738175/yii2-user-identity-loss-after-page-redirection)

Comment: Do you have the public property `public $enableSession = true;` in your custom class?

Comment: That property is by default set to true

Comment: Only if your class extends the original class I think.. I may try...

Answer (score 1):

The problem was in `findIdentity` method that didn't return any results. 
It should be

```
public static function findIdentity($id)
{
    return Admin::findOne($id)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Post content of $model->login().

Then I'll check if session cookie is correctly set after login.